# Regex to get strings between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string with 0-n parameters in it noted between brackets.
I want to get the words that are between brackets. For example:

> this [is] a [test]

Should return the array `['is', 'test']`

I'm not an expert on regular expressions and I've lost a lot of time on this.
Here is what I currently have but it is not working.

```
var regex = /\[([^}]+)\]/;
var m = "this [is] a [test]".match(regex);
console.log(m);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gtfLL47/)**

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/7gtfLL47/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following regex, you're using wrong bracket

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/nQ2cE6/1)

```
/\[([^\]]+)\]/
```

You can also use

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/nQ2cE6/2)

```
/\[(\w+)\]/
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `String#match` as you need captured texts. Use `RegExp#exec` with a global flag:

```js
var regex = /\[([^\]]+)]/g; // RegExp has a global flag to find all matches
var arr = [];                // An array for our captured texts
while ((m = regex.exec("this [is] a [test]")) !== null) {
       arr.push(m[1]);       // Captured text is inside Group 1
}
console.log(arr);
```

Regex breakdown:

- `\[` - opening literal square bracket
- `([^\]]+)` - a capture group matching any symbol other than `]` (note that it must be escaped inside a character class)
- `]` - a literal `]` (note that it does not have to be escaped outside a character class).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this regex:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nQ2cE6/3)**